# Convert from tagRECT/CRect to Gdiplus::Rect

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi+

What is the easiest way to convert a `RECT` struct (`tagRECT`) or a `CRect` to a `Gdiplus::Rect`?

```
Gdiplus::Rect tmpRect(rect.top, rect.left, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
```

works but is a lot of typing.

Answer (score 3):

The signature is `Rect([in] INT x, [in]  INT y, [in]  INT width, [in]  INT height);` so it should be

```
Gdiplus::Rect CopyRect(RECT &rect)
{
    return Gdiplus::Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
}
```

Comment: Good catch; but: you should add this as a comment to the other question instead of adding it as a separate answer (and then delete this answer).

Answer (score 2):

If the interface for Gdiplus::Rect doesn't have a convenient constructor, you can make your own function once and use it everywhere.

```
Gdiplus::Rect CopyRect(const RECT &rect)
{
    return Gdiplus::Rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
}
```